# How To pass Element Id In Javascript As Argument or parameter

Tags: javascript

how it is possible to get element from the id of input element and pass it 
as parameter to java script function.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="name">
 <input type="button" onclick="call(id_of_input_type_text)" value="Click 
  me">
 <script>
 var call(id_of_input_type_text) = function(){
 var x = document.getElementById(id_of_input_type_text).value;
 alert(x);
 }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Sir/Mam I want to use single function like validation and get there value by pass id in the function so please help me regarding this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same function with different arguments for each call. Like you can use:

```
<input type="button" onclick="call('name')" value="Click Me">
```

And it will alert the value of input field with id 'name'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Option 1 (from your question):

Note you can use `call('name')` in this case.

```js
var call = function(id){
  var x = document.getElementById(id).value;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" onclick="call(document.getElementById('name').id)" value="Click me">
```

Option 2 (send the element, so you won't need to get it in the function):

```js
var call = function(elem){
  var x = elem.value;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" onclick="call(document.getElementById('name'))" value="Click me">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below code as reference:

```html
<body>
 <input type="text" id="name">
 <input type="button" onClick="call('name')" value="Click me" id="btnOne">

 
 <script type="text/javascript">
var call = function(elementId)
{
 var valueOfInput = document.getElementById(elementId).value
    alert(valueOfInput);
}
</script>
 </body>
```